# What am I doing wrong? [Rails, belongs_to]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Stuck on nested forms..

Order model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

end
```

User mode:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

end
```

Form view:

```
=form_for @order do |order|
    =order.fields_for :user, @order.user do |user|
        .row
            .col-md-3
                .form-group
                    =user.label :first_name, "Name"
                    =user.text_field :first_name, :class => "form-control"
            .col-md-3
                .form-group
                    =user.label :last_name, "Last name"
                    =user.text_field :last_name, :class => "form-control"
            .col-md-3
                    =user.label :email, "Email"
                    =user.text_field :email, :class => "form-control"
            .col-md-3
                    =user.label :telephone, "Phone"
                    =user.text_field :telephone, :class => "form-control"

        .row
            .col-md-4.margin-top-15
                =order.submit 'Send', :class => 'btn btn-success'
```

OrdersController:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @order = Order.new
    if user_signed_in?
       user = current_user
    else
       user = User.new
    end
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.new order_attributes
    @order.save
  end

  private

    def order_attributes
      params.require(:order).permit(:user_id, user_attributes: [:id, :user_id, :user, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :telephone, :password, :password_confirmation])
    end

end
```

So this is what I am trying to do:

User model has devise. I want to create order and assign to it user_id. On submit it tells me "Unpermitted parameter: user". Order model creates its column, but nothing goes to user model.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do the submitted parameters look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
params.require(:order).permit(:user_id, user_attributes: [:id,...
```

to:

```
params.require(:order).permit(:user_id, user: [:id,...
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for reply. I guess it's due local variable 'user', right? Say if I want to use @user instead of user to make it available in view as well (i.e. I need to make filled fields by current_user information). In this case I need to use users_attributes.

Comment: Read about strong parameters at http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: I've read. My question is more related to nested forms and what is the right way to compose fields_for.. how to permit params and attributes is pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `:user` from `:user_attributes`.
And I don't think `:user_id` is necessary.